# autoconf doesn't enable feature...

Tags: autotools, configure, autoconf

I want to have a configure option called "stdout" in my configure.ac which results in defining a variable to be "1" or "0". Here is what I put into the configure.ac:

```
 AC_ARG_ENABLE([stdout],
   [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-stdout[=yes/no], --disable-stdout],
     [Enable or disable output to stdout. Default is disabled.])],
   [ if test "x$enableval" = "yes" ; then
       AC_DEFINE([WRITETOSTDOUT],[1],[Enable output to stdout])
     else
       AC_DEFINE([WRITETOSTDOUT],[0],[Disable output to stdout])
     fi ],
   [AC_DEFINE([WRITETOSTDOUT],[0],[Enable output to stdout])])
```

What I expect is that when I add to `configure` the option `--enable-stdout` or `--enable-stdout=yes`, I get a `#define WRITETOSTDOUT 1` and when I add `--disable-stdout` or `--enable-stdout=no`, I get a `#define WRITETOSTDOUT 0`

It works as expected **except** that `--enable-stdout` (without parameter) results in `#define WRITETOSTDOUT 0`

Another observation is that when I type `configure --enable-std` and press  it competes to `./configure --enable-stdout=`

How do I get the simple enable-option to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret is that you should name your shell variable `enable_`*foo* for `--enable-`*foo* or `--disable-`*foo*.  So:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE([stdout],
 [AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-stdout=yes|no],
                 [Enable or disable output to stdout. Default is disabled.])],
 [enable_stdout="$enableval"],
 [enable_stdout="no"])

 ...
 stdout_val=0
 if test "x$enable_stdout" = "xyes" ; then
   stdout_val=1
 fi
 AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([WRITETOSTDOUT],[$stdout_val],[Enable output to stdout])
```

The [Autotools Mythbuster](http://www.flameeyes.eu/autotools-mythbuster/autoconf/arguments.html) pages have a few examples of this.

Comment: that looks much cleaner, and most of all works... except for two minor flaws: the comment in config.h is always "Disable..." and tab-completion still gives a "=". The first is the one that bothers me more...

Comment: The first is easily fixed.  I've never tried argument completion for configure.  My environment doesn't seem to do it.